# How to create controller using command prompt in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I  am new to zend framework.I have placed my bin and  library folder in :

`C:\xampp\htdocs\zend`

and have created project using command prompt.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\bin> zf create project zendtest
```

its creating project zendtest in folder -> `C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\bin\`

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\bin>cd zendtest
```

but when i tried to create module

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\bin\zendtest> zf create module testmodule
```

its saying `'zf' is not recognised as internal or external command .`

On creating controller also giving same error.

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to your system's PATH. Take a look here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.extending.html#zend.tool.extending.zend-tool-framework.cli-client.setup-windows

Should be as simple as adding the path to your Zend Framework's bin folder to the PATH, and you should be set.

Comment: i have given this in system's path   C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\;   again its giving same error  and in php.ini i have given this                    include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library"

Comment: Done by using C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\bin; in system's path  Thanks tcole

Answer (score 0):

First you have to go to your project path and then move to path from where your command will run

> c:\xampp\htdocs\project_name>..\Zend\bin\zf.bat create module
>   module_name