# How to create a controller and display in browser in zend?

Tags: zend-framework

i am new in zend framework. Please help me to create controller and how navigate in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best question, because it shows you haven't searched much. Let's search together:

[framework.zend.com](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.quickstart.html)

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083705/how-to-create-controller-using-command-prompt-in-zend-framework)

[StackOverflow again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385960/how-to-create-new-controller-in-zend-framework)

[StackOverflow 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507492/zend-framework-2-add-new-controller)

So either search better or please try to explain your need with more details and show what you have already done.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is pretty vague.

I'm assuming that you have some experience with computers, computer programming, the Linux operating system, and developing for the web. Object oriented programming principles, as well as some awareness of php itself are also going to be very helpful.

Do you have an environment to work from? A webserver that's capable of running php? You'll need that, as a bare minimum first. Luckily we live in the days when it's easy to set up virtual environments for that. Try puphpet. It's awesome. While you're at it, make sure you get MySQL, as you'll need it for many of the tutorials provided by Zend (and others).

https://puphpet.com/

Have you downloaded the framework?

If you use the zf tool to create a project, as described in the link below, you'll have a basic application that includes a Controller and that you should be able to browse to.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

That should be enough to get you going.